# mustache {{{partial}}} vs {{> partial}}

Tags: mustache, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars/mustache layout file in my node.js application that looks like this:

```
{{> header}}
{{> navbar}}
{{{body}}}
{{> footer-user}}
{{> footer}}
```

Since all five lines are includes, is there any difference between the two types of includes? Could I replace {{{body}}} with {{>body}} or {{> header}} with {{{header}}}? They both appear not to escape the html that gets included. What's the best practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `{{> name}}` is for partials, i.e. to include another template:

> Handlebars allows for template reuse through partials. Partials are
>   normal Handlebars templates that may be called directly by other
>   templates.

whereas `{{{name}}}` is for including data without escaping it. If you wanted the data to be escaped, you'd use `{{name}}`:

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you
>   don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", {{{.

So they are different things.

`{{{body}}}` refers to a `body` property in the current context provided by your application (alternatively it could refer to a helper function but that's not the case here).

If you had `{{>body}}` in the code, it would mean you have a template named `body` that you want handlebars to load.

Note that, if you use Handlebars proper, all partials need to be registered by calling `Handlebars.registerPartial` (if your project uses `express-handlebars`, it does it all for you so you won't find this in the code).

Handlebars's documentation can be found at [handlebarsjs.com](http://handlebarsjs.com).